# how to create a list from a set of derived classes?

Tags: c++, inheritance, std

Let's say I have a set of following classes:

```
class animal
{
// members, constructors and other methods...

public:
    virtual void what_do_you_eat() { cout << "i eat generic food" << endl; }
}

class cat : public animal
{
// members, constructors and other methods...

public:
    void what_do_you_eat() { cout << "i eat cat food" << endl; }
}

class dog : public animal
{
// members, constructors and other methods...

public:
    void what_do_you_eat() { cout << "i eat dog food" << endl; }
}
```

and I want to create a list (any container would be fine, but let's choose `std::list<>` for this example):

```
std::list<animal> animals
animals.push_back( dog() );
animals.push_back( cat() );
```

but when I try to iterate over the list I get this output:

```
for(auto itr : animals)
{
    itr.what_do_you_eat();
}
// output:
// i eat generic food
// i eat generic food
// i eat generic food
// i eat generic food
// ...
```

I tried then to make a list of pointers (`std::list<animal *> animals`), output was correct, but there are many issues with this solution:

- because the standard says that stl containers can't hold a const type I can't use a list of `std::list<animal * const> animals` and pointers held by `animals` can be overwritten anywhere in my program.
- I need to release them manually.

**Question:** 
Is there any possibility to pass a derived class into an stl container, through a reference to a base class, and still get the right output?

Is there any workaround to do this correctly without pointers? Currently, I am writing a project that depends heavily on class inheritance, and I am stuck right now because I need to create a list of objects of different types (all of these types inherit directly or indirectly from a single base class) **and it seems to be impossible.**

solutions involving `boost` library are acceptable.

Answer (score 5):

When you are handling polymorphism container must use pointers of any kind.
It is best to use smart pointer and in your case `std::unique_ptr` will do the job perfectly.

So for example:

```
std::list<std::unieque_ptr<animal>> animals;

animals.emplace_back(new dog {});
animals.emplace_back(new cat {});
```

Note base class `animal` has to have a virtual destructor!
It is best to define this as an abstract class:

```
class animal
{
// NO members, NO constructors only pure virtual methods
public:
    virtual ~animal() {};
    virtual void what_do_you_eat() = 0; 
};
```

Answer (score -1):

In your code,  `list<animal>` should be  `list<animal*>` and then you must change other lines of the code accordingly.

See the code below. It works as you expected.

```
class animal
{
// members, constructors and other methods...

public:
             animal(){}
    virtual ~animal(){}

    virtual void what_do_you_eat() { cout << "i eat generic food" << endl; }
};

class cat : public animal
{
// members, constructors and other methods...


public:
             cat(){}
    virtual ~cat(){}

    void what_do_you_eat() { cout << "i eat cat food" << endl; }
};

class dog : public animal
{
// members, constructors and other methods...

public:
             dog(){}
    virtual ~dog(){}

    void what_do_you_eat() { cout << "i eat dog food" << endl; }
};

int main() {

    std::list<animal*> animals;
    animal *a=new animal();
    dog *d=new dog();
    cat *c = new cat();

    animals.push_back( a );
    animals.push_back( d );
    animals.push_back( c );

    for (std::list<animal*>::iterator itr=animals.begin(); itr!=animals.end(); ++itr)
    {

        (*itr)->what_do_you_eat();
    }

  return 0;
}
```